# Split string delimited by comma without respect to commas in brackets

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I've got a string like

```
s="abc, 3rncd (23uh, sdfuh), 32h(q23q)89 (as), dwe8h, edt (1,wer,345,rtz,tr t), nope";
```

and I want to split it into those string

```
String[] parts={"abc", "3rncd (23uh, sdfuh)", "32h(q23q)89 (as)", "dwe8h", "edt (1,wer,345,rtz,tr t)", "nope"};
```

If I simply call `s.split(",")` then after trimming I would get a different result because in some of those string, for example `"3rncd (23uh, sdfuh)"` there is still a comma. But I don't want to could commas in brackets. Is there an elegant way to solve that problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string at commas except when in bracket environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808913/split-string-at-commas-except-when-in-bracket-environment)

Comment: Except for there it is python.

Comment: Don't you want to ignore comas in inside quotes instead ? Don't know python much, but csv parsing libs do handle this efficiently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `(` and `)` are not nested and unescaped. You can use split using:

```
String[] arr = input.split(",(?![^()]*\\))\\s*");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wK4bC6/1)

`,(?![^()]*\))` will match a comma if it is NOT followed by a non-parentheses text and `)`, thus ignoring commas inside `(` and `)`.

Comment: In your demo you've selected "pcre (php)". Is this what Java uses?

Comment: That is just for demo purpose. There is nothing PCRE specific in `",(?![^()]*\\))\\s*"` and it works in Java as well.

Comment: This is a bad answer, the lookahead is open ended, relies on parenthesis to keep from looking to the end of string. And it has to do this with every comma it finds. @principal-ideal-domain you should take note of that !

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: I wouldn't use the lookahead solution for this.

If you have a lot of commas, the lookahead will have a latency that is
logarithmic, relative to the amount of commas.

The reason is that a lookahead used like this can be *open ended*.
If there is a posibility that there could be nothing to terminating the lookaead
it's not a good idea. Especially on a large sample of data.

Every time the regex finds a comma, it has to do this `(?![^()]*\))`

What that does is lookahead until it finds parenthesis.
That means it will match comma's as well.

If you have a string like this `asdf,asdf,asdf,aasdf,aaaasdf,asdf,aasdf,asdf`
the progression is

Match 1:  found `,` looked ahead at all of this `asdf,asdf,aasdf,aaaasdf,asdf,aasdf,asdf`
Match 2:  found `,` looked ahead at all of this `asdf,aasdf,aaaasdf,asdf,aasdf,asdf`
Match 3:  found `,` looked ahead at all of this `aasdf,aaaasdf,asdf,aasdf,asdf`
Match 4:  found `,` looked ahead at all of this `aaaasdf,asdf,aasdf,asdf`
Match 5:  found `,` looked ahead at all of this `asdf,aasdf,asdf`
Match 6:  found `,` looked ahead at all of this `aasdf,asdf`
Match 7:  found `,` looked ahead at all of this `asdf`

It's a pretty small string to be matching all of that stuff.

**It's never good to use a regex like that, for split or any kind of matching.**

---

I'd just match the field values in a global find.

```
"(?:\\A|\\G,\\s*)([^(),]*(?:(?:\\([^()]*\\))[^(),]*)*)"
```

---

Here is a simple benchmark that demonstrates the said latency using
a lookahead like this can cause:

Sample:  260 characters, 42 commas

```
asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,
asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,
asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,
asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,
asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,
asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,
asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,asdf,
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (?:\A|\G,\s*)([^(),]*(?:(?:\([^()]*\))[^(),]*)*)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   50
Elapsed Time:    2.97 s,   2972.45 ms,   2972454 µs


Regex2:   ,(?![^()]*\))\s*
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   49
Elapsed Time:    21.59 s,   21586.81 ms,   21586811 µs
```

When the sample is doubled, the time gets ever worse..

```
Regex1:   (?:\A|\G,\s*)([^(),]*(?:(?:\([^()]*\))[^(),]*)*)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   99
Elapsed Time:    5.89 s,   5887.16 ms,   5887163 µs


Regex2:   ,(?![^()]*\))\s*
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   98
Elapsed Time:    83.06 s,   83063.77 ms,   83063772 µs
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this will work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="abc, 3rncd (23uh, sdfuh), 32h(q23q)89 (as), dwe8h, edt (1,wer,345,rtz,tr t), nope";
    String[] arr = s.split(",\\s(?!\\w+\\))");
    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
abc
3rncd (23uh, sdfuh)
32h(q23q)89 (as)
dwe8h
edt (1,wer,345,rtz,tr t)
nope
```