# How to read a CSV dialect containing a list in square brackets?

Tags: python, csv

I get CSV lines of the form

`a,b,c,[1,2,3,4]`

and I want to extract

```
a
b
c
[1,2,3,4]
```

But with

`csv.reader([message], delimiter=',')`

I get

```
a
b
c
[1
2
3
4]
```

This is not particularly surprising, but I wonder how I can specify a dialect so that the CSV line is correctly parsed. Is this even a valid dialect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string delimited by comma without respect to commas in brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660285/split-string-delimited-by-comma-without-respect-to-commas-in-brackets)

Comment: While @Asocia links a Java solution, you will probably have to do some string magic, like replacing `[` and `]` with `"[` and `]"`, then use CSV parser, or drop the use of CSV parser and go with manual parsing, presumably with a regex as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) accepts a [`quotechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) keyword parameter, which tells it to ignore delimiters (`,`) inside the `quotechar` value. By default, it's set to a double-quote `"`. That can be used to group `[1,2,3,4]` as one column value. Unfortunately, your "quotes" come as square brackets which come as 2 characters `[` and `]` and you can't assign them both to `quotechar`.

The typical trick is to convert to the same `quotechar` value, either all `[` to `]` or all `]` to `[`, then call

```
csv.reader(data, quotechar='[')  # or ']' whichever you replaced everything into
```

If your input CSV isn't that big and you can read it all in-memory, you can read the entire file, replace all brackets to the same "shape", store the converted lines into an [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) in-memory text stream, then pass that to `csv.reader` to read each row:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

converted = StringIO()
with open('data.csv') as file:
    converted.write(file.read().replace('[', ']'))
print(converted.getvalue())

converted.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(converted, quotechar=']')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    print(*row, sep='\n')
```

```
a,b,c,]1,2,3,4]
d,e,f,]4,5,6,7]

['a', 'b', 'c', '1,2,3,4']
a
b
c
1,2,3,4
['d', 'e', 'f', '4,5,6,7']
d
e
f
4,5,6,7
```

But if you need the square brackets in the parsed contents, as you mentioned:

> and I want to extract
>
> ```
> a
> b
> c
> [1,2,3,4]
> ```

Then one option is to use some *other* `quotechar` value (let's say `;`) and put it beside each square bracket, like this:

```
a,b,c,;[1,2,3,4];
d,e,f,;[4,5,6,7];
```

Then use the same trick to replace all the brackets with bracket+`;`, and then this time use `csv.reader(data, quotechar=';')`:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

converted = StringIO()
with open('data.csv') as file:
    converted.write(file.read().replace('[', ';[').replace(']', '];'))
print(converted.getvalue())

converted.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(converted, quotechar=';')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    print(*row, sep='\n')
```

```
a,b,c,;[1,2,3,4];
d,e,f,;[4,5,6,7];

['a', 'b', 'c', '[1,2,3,4]']
a
b
c
[1,2,3,4]
['d', 'e', 'f', '[4,5,6,7]']
d
e
f
[4,5,6,7]
```

If the CSV is too big though to store all the lines in-memory, you might need to save it back to a *new* file first, then re-open and re-read it with `csv.reader` with a proper `quotechar`.

Comment: Thank you alot, I continued with the second option