# Regular expression that splits preferences with ties

Tags: python, regex

Consider the .toi data files which represents election data where ties are allowed (e.g., see [here](http://www.preflib.org/data/election/burlington/ED-00005-00000001.toi)).

Each line may look like "1,1,{5,6,4},2,3", which means that one voter wrote
"1,{5,6,4},2,3" which means he prefers candidate 1, if not then any of candidates 5,6,4. If non of the previous are elected, he prefers 2 over 3.

I'd like to write a regex that will break these lines into a Python list where each position is list cell.

For the example above, the output should `['1','{5,6,4}', '2', '3']`.

Also, there could be more than one "tie", i.e., the vote {1,2},5,{3,4},6 is also legal and should be converted into `['{1,2}','5','{3,4}','6']`.

This can obviously be done using a simple loop, but I was wondering if it's doable using a regular expression. The commas within the candidate ties makes this one somewhat tricky :) .

Comment: See [*Split string at commas except when in bracket environment*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808913/split-string-at-commas-except-when-in-bracket-environment): `re.split(r',\s*(?![^{}]*\})', data)`

Comment: Check this :- https://regex101.com/r/gN5nD3/3

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I already have a code working with a loop similar to the one in the question you pointed to. Simply from a curiosity perspective I was wondering how would such regex look.

Comment: The second answer in the post I linked to provides the regex, see my comment above.