# How to parse a CSV with commas between parenthesis and missing values

Tags: python, csv, pyparsing

I tried using `pyparsing` to parse a CSV with:

- **Commas between parenthesis (or brackets, etc):** "a(1,2),b" should return the list ["a(1,2)","b"]
- **Missing values:** "a,b,,c," should return the list ['a','b','','c','']

I worked a solution but it seems "dirty". Mainly, the `Optional` inside only one of the possible atomics. I think the optional should be independent of the atomics. That is, I feel it should be put somewhere else, for example in the `delimitedList` optional arguments, but in my trial and error that was the only place that worked and made sense. It could be in any of the possible atomics so I chose the first.

Also, I don't fully understand what `originalTextFor` is doing but if I remove it it stops working.

Working example:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# Function that parses a line of columns separated by commas and returns a list of the columns
def fromLineToRow(line):
    sqbrackets_col = pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars="[],") | pp.nestedExpr(opener="[",closer="]")  # matches "a[1,2]"
    parens_col = pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars="(),") | pp.nestedExpr(opener="(",closer=")")      # matches "a(1,2)"
    # In the following line:
    # * The "^" means "choose the longest option"
    # * The "pp.Optional" can be in any of the expressions separated by "^". I put it only on the first. It's used for when there are missing values
    atomic = pp.originalTextFor(pp.Optional(pp.OneOrMore(parens_col))) ^ pp.originalTextFor(pp.OneOrMore(sqbrackets_col))

    grammar = pp.delimitedList(atomic)

    row = grammar.parseString(line).asList()
    return row

file_str = \
"""YEAR,a(2,3),b[3,4]
1960,2.8,3
1961,4,
1962,,1
1963,1.27,3"""

for line in file_str.splitlines():
    row = fromLineToRow(line)
    print(row)
```

Prints:

```
['YEAR', 'a(2,3)', 'b[3,4]']
['1960', '2.8', '3']
['1961', '4', '']
['1962', '', '1']
['1963', '1.27', '3']
```

Is this the right way to do this? Is there a "cleaner" way to use the `Optional` inside the first atomic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working inside-out, I get this:

```
# chars not in ()'s or []'s - also disallow ','
non_grouped = pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars="[](),")

# grouped expressions in ()'s or []'s
grouped = pp.nestedExpr(opener="[",closer="]") | pp.nestedExpr(opener="(",closer=")")

# use OneOrMore to allow non_grouped and grouped together
atomic = pp.originalTextFor(pp.OneOrMore(non_grouped | grouped))
# or based on your examples, you *could* tighten this up to:
# atomic = pp.originalTextFor(non_grouped + pp.Optional(grouped))
```

`originalTextFor` recombines the original input text within the leading and trailing boundaries of the matched expressions, and returns a single string. If you leave this out, then you will get all the sub-expressions in a nested list of strings, like `['a',['2,3']]`. You *could* rejoin them with repeated calls to `''.join`, but that would collapse out whitespace (or use `' '.join`, but that has the opposite problem of potentially introducing whitespace).

To optionalize the elements of the list, just say so in the definition of the delimited list:

```
grammar = pp.delimitedList(pp.Optional(atomic, default=''))
```

Be sure to add the default value, else the empty slots will just get dropped.

With these changes I get:

```
['YEAR', 'a(2,3)', 'b[3,4]']
['1960', '2.8', '3']
['1961', '4', '']
['1962', '', '1']
['1963', '1.27', '3']
```

Comment: For parse-time conversion of numeric values, change `atomic` to: `atomic = pp.pyparsing_common.number | pp.originalTextFor(... etc.`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using regex `re`, for instance:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', line1)
['a(1,2)', 'b']
>>> re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', line2)
['a', 'b', '', 'c', '']
```

Comment: line1 parsing should be ["a(1,2)","b"] instead of ['a(1', '2)', 'b'] (the comma inside the parenthesis shouldn't be a delimiter)

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach before trying pyparsing but when I start to add square brackets or any other type of nested expressions then the regex gets more and more illegible

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open('44289614.csv') as f:
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        l = re.split(',\s*(?![^()[]]*[\)\]])', line)
        print(len(l), l)
```

Output:

```
3 ['YEAR', 'a(2,3)', 'b[3,4]']
3 ['1960', '2.8', '3']
3 ['1961', '4', '']
3 ['1962', '', '1']
3 ['1963', '1.27', '3']
```

Modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809170/778533).

I also like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648570/778533), which suggests modifying the input slightly and using [quotechar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) of the `csv` module.